# Does the image of A equal to the image of the transpose of A

Tags: linear-algebra

For a linear transformation $A$ from $V$ to $V$, Are the following true?

1) $ker(A) + im(A) = V$

2) $ker(A) + ker(A)^\perp = V$

3) $ker(A) + ker(A^*)^\perp = V$, with $A^*$ as the hermitian transpose.

---

If so, doesn't this imply $im(A) = im(A^*)$? And $ker(A) = ker(A^*)$? In other words, the transpose of a matrix spans the same subspace?

Comment: For $(1)$ consider
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself.  Can you show that $im(A)=ker(A)$?

Comment: Michael's matrix is also an example where ${\rm im}(A)\ne{\rm im}(A^*)$.

Comment: nevermind wrong arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

2) is true since for every subspace $U\leq V$ we have $U+U^\perp=V$